# Wrong backgroundcolor on ListView inflate

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

So I have a `ListView` that uses a custom adapter. I want the background color of an item be either red or green, depending on a value I get out of my database with `getDBValue();` (this works).

The problem is, when the activity is first opened, and so the listview is inflated, all listview items have the same (not correct) green background color. When I start scrolling though, the background are set correctly.

How do I get the right background color when listview inflates and where does my program "error"?

I already have debugged it and the `dbValue` is returning the correct value.

This is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
}

private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
    View v;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // first time views are created
        v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }

    String dbvalue = getDBValue();

    if(!dbvalue.equals("me")){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(230, 255, 0x00, 0x00));
    }else{
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(230, 0x00, 255, 0x00));
    }

    setViewText((TextView) v, text);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: the green is the 'else' condition? if it is, maybe your dbvalue is not returning the correct values (at first time you build the view)

Comment: That's my thougth but when debugging, the value is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done this thing in my app,

Please make drawable for that, and apply in view,
here i share method which set drawable, check it.

Please call this method in `createViewFromResource` So, this will work.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setdrwable(Drawable drawable,View view)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=16)
    {
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    }
    else
    {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```